# R shiny - tabPanel and output

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my code:

```
shinyServer <-  function(input, output) {

    output$text_out <- renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected", input$text_input)
    })

  }

shinyUI <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("censusVis"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, textInput('text_input', label = 'some label', value ='')),
    column(9,
           tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel('result',
                          fluidRow(
                            column(12, h3('Test_header'),  
                                   textOutput('text_out')
                            )
                          )
                ),
                tabPanel('some panel', tableOutput('table')),
                tabPanel('another panel', tableOutput('table'))

          )
    )
  )

)
shinyApp(ui=shinyUI, server = shinyServer)
```

It works, but it does not display line `"You have selected"`, if I comment the following line in code `tabPanel('another panel', tableOutput('table'))`, then line `"You have selected"` shows up. Do you know what is wrong, Why tabPanel affects output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use same output `tableOutput('table')` two times in two tabPanel. Thats why it didnt show the `text_out`. Use this-

```
shinyServer <-  function(input, output) {

    output$text_out <- renderText({ 
        paste("You have selected", input$text_input)
    })

}

shinyUI <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("censusVis"),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 3, textInput('text_input', label = 'some label', value ='')),
        column(width = 9,
               tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel(title = 'result',
                            fluidRow(
                                column(width = 12, 
                                       h3('Test_header'),  
                                       textOutput('text_out')
                                )
                            )
                   ),
                   tabPanel(title = 'some panel', 
                            tableOutput('table1')
                   ),
                   tabPanel(title = 'another panel',
                            tableOutput('table2')
                   )
               )
        )
    )
)
shinyApp(ui=shinyUI, server = shinyServer)
```